# Is there php benchmarking tool like chrome's timeline

Tags: php, benchmarking

Open google chrome, browsing your favorite website, then right click > open inspect element, and go to timeline tab, you can record timeline rendered by google chrome.

Is there any php benchmarking tool to retrieve information, get timeline of functions, and variables rendered by webserver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most known tool is Xdebug.
However, manual *code profiling* (that's that this thing is called) is no less effective. Just put a few `microtime(1)` calls into code, analyze output and move them accordingly

Comment: Yes xdebug, and webgrind , Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Many frameworks have built-in profiling objects. CodeIgniter has a very nice profiling tool you can use:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html

Example:

```
$this->benchmark->mark('my_mark_start');

// Some code happens here...

$this->benchmark->mark('my_mark_end'); 

$this->benchmark->mark('another_mark_start');

// Some more code happens here...

$this->benchmark->mark('another_mark_end');
```

Comment: Yea it is. One of [my co-workers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/205343/justin-lucas) extended it to provide a really nice UI for the producers and devs to easily spot bottlenecks over time.

Comment: @Matt what's so nice in it? I's just setting benchmarks. It can be done without any CI or any other frameworks, easily. And it does not automatic profiling, like xdebug

Comment: XDebug is not nearly as painless to install as CI. Devil's advocate = XDebug is my best friend locally. PHPStorm + XDebug makes stepping through my code and debugging super nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **XHProf**, which is FB ( ~ 2011 ) developed to replace xdebug. I have attached some screen shots and you can tell if it has what you need :)

[image]

[image]

[image]